# How to set up Domain Whitelist in PhoneGap Build?

Tags: cordova, whitelist

According to Apache Cordova Documentation,  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

we need to delcare access to specific network domains and subdomains in domain whitelist if we want a native application to access to outside domains.

If I use PhoneGap Build, how to set up the domain whitelist? Or we don't need to set it up at all when we use PhoneGap Build?

Please help me if anyone knows about it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using config.xml, Look at this guide to know how to make config.xml   https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

Comment: Link is dead. 404 :(